# code within continueWithBlock executed but result is not immediate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, amazon-dynamodb

The problem I'm facing is that I called pushViewController after a task is completed. The compiler did go within the block but the result happens only about a minute later.

E.g.

> > [[AWSManager sharedInstance] loginWithUsername:_usernameTf.text password:_passwordTf.text completion:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
> >
> > Compiler comes here and called pushViewController. However, on simulator  the result happens only about a minute later. It should happen immediately.
> >
> > }];

Thanks!

Comment: Always do UI updates on the main thread.

Comment: May I know how to do that? That means after i called pushViewController, I have to call a function that does UI updates?

Comment: it works now thanks!! how to mark your answer as correct?